# Issues building a a URL for a script to move a PTZ camera

Tags: javascript

I'm building a script so that users can move the IP camera without having to login with the admin. You are able to send commands like this: https://[ipaddress]/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?move=[up/down/left/right] but I'm into running issues. I think it's with the URL that's been built, because there are no console errors.

Here's what I have:

```
<body>
         <script>
         function showURL(direction){
         
         var e = document.getElementById("ip");
         var ip = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
         
            
            //var move = $("movement").find(":selected").attr("value");
            var url = 'https://' + ip + '/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?move=' + direction;
         document.location.nref = url;
         
                }
      </script>
<p>Select a room from the list</p>

         <select id="ip">
            <option value="">Choose a room:</option>
            <option value="0.0.0.0">B12</option>
            <option value="0.0.0.1">B13</option>
            <option value="0.0.0.2">B14</option>
         </select>

         <div class="box">
            <br><br>
            <a style="text-decoration: none; color: black" href="#" onclick="showURL('up');">Up</a>
         </div>


   </body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should use APIs like mentioned over here https://web.dev/camera-pan-tilt-zoom/